# What is the meaning of "would-be"?

Tags: meaning-in-context

> Kass hastens to add, though, that the candidates must also demonstrate emotional and psychological stability, coupled with an extremely strong sense of purpose. In effect, the **would-be** astronauts must be equipped to accept that they will be living on Mars for the rest of their lives.

I don't understand the word *would-be*.

Comment: A very common equivalent in popular / informal / speech contexts is [wannabee](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/wannabee) *- a person who wants or aspires to be someone or something else or who tries to look or act like someone else*

Comment: definition of [would-be](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/american/would-be) Sense 1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"The [would-be](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/would-be?q=would-be) astronauts" means "those who are hoping to become astronauts."

You can use *would-be* before a noun, such as in *would-be actor*, *would-be manager*, *would-be parents*.

Comment: +1 to u , so why they don't say would be astonauts ? why the - ?

Comment: @MarcoDinatsoli When a phrase is used as attributive, it is written with hyphens. That is what happens with _32-bit_ in "a 32-bit processor." Exaggerating, you could also write "He is the I-know-everything man my sister doesn't like."

Comment: strange very strange sentence yours

Comment: Probably, the more correct sentence would be "He is the I-know-everything kind of man my syster doesn't like."

Answer (score 0):

*would be* is like they *would become* something

> They **would be(come)** astronauts in four years.

Here it is expected that they will become astronauts. *would be* is an verb.

*would-be* is like *wishing or pretending* to become something. *would-be* is an adjective.

> The **would-be** astronauts have high hopes of travelling in space. (Its possible)
>
> The **would-be** astronauts failed the written exam. (Its not possible)